New tag for opening discussions
During my study of Chinese, I feel as if there is a big level gap between those in the academic field and those learning Chinese through conversation/beginner learners. I wish to open a question/discussion discussing different types of grammer usage, specifically those pertaining to questions you will see in school tests and in the academic field. It will help increase the amount of daily questions, as well as allow foreign Chinese learners understand and have a better grasp of the difference in curriculum compared to Native Chinese learners.
For example, showing the different variations of how to phrase a question and the types of questions one will see on a test.
1. 下列關於 XX藥物 之敘述，何者 正確? would be "better" translated as -> Which of the following statements are correct for the drug XX. 

XX藥物 可用於治療巴金森症，其作用機轉為何? -> Drug XX can be used to treat Parkinson, what is its mechanism?

I think questions like these with explanations on the bolded words will help those learning Chinese have more exposure to the more academic/test style/formal Chinese. 
What do you think of this idea and its plausibility in Language Stack Exchange? Should this type of question-type-discussion be limited to the non-existent chat forum only? Should Chinese SE be focused on asking only specific questions/answers?

Well, since SE sites are not forums, I'm afraid discussions are not part of its model. However, this might be a way to help increase participation in chat. Also the chat is deserted because whenever people go there, no-one is already there. 
And so on and so forth, like a vicious circle. Maybe organizing events in the chat to speak about something would help increase the number of users speaking there. Even having two types of events, one to be held in Chinese, and the other to be held in English speaking about Chinese grammar, like a point or a particular expression.

I agree it would be nice to have higher level questions on Chinese.SE.  Not every question is simply "is this grammatically correct?" or "what's the difference between X and Y?"  And among the reasons to do so would be to attract people who are more serious about studying Chinese, and not just the "what does [random photo] say?" folks who disappear moments later.
Stack Exchange, however, is fundamentally not a chat site.  It deliberately obstructs discussion.  But there are ways to phrase "discussion" in the form of questions and answers.
I've been using writing-critique to write snippets and ask for critiques.  When it comes down to it, I no longer need to have every single thing explained to me in detail, and in fact, it's inefficient.
Another possible option:  There's a Translation Golf question style on Spanish.SE which I think might be useful here.  For example:

Translation Golf XXII - The Neverending Story

AURYN gives you great power … but you must not make use of it. For the Childlike Empress herself ...

The goal is to translate the given text to Spanish, using as few letters as possible, while keeping all the original text's meaning and concepts more or less intact.

Rules: Translation-golf rules

The translation must be accurate and respect the original sentence
The OP always needs to propose a first attempt of translation to Spanish
The translation with the least number of characters wins
...



We might need to think outside the box, however, and figure out a way to make it suit the Stack Exchange platform.
